# camel aggregate lines and split into files of different sizes

Tags: apache-camel

1. My route read a file with a number of lines and filter some lines out.

It  split the file on lines and filter and aggregate to a file.
The file uri is in append mode so each aggregation is appended to it. A **done file** is created everytime I write to it.

2. After the file is fully written to, another route picks up the file.
   This route split the file into files of n files of equal number of records. But I am running into an issue where the **done file** is updated for every aggregation in step 1.

How do I update the done file only when the aggregation is fully done ?

I tried to use property ${exchangeProperty.CamelBatchComplete}  in the route1. 
But that property is always set to true on aggregation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its harder to help with just a bit confusing description of your use-case without some basic code example. However you can just write the done file yourself when you are done, its a few lines of Java code

Comment: Thanks, its been a steep learning curve. I am trying to learn it in a hurry.